# Specification for complex url query strings

Tags: node.js, url, query-string

I've been experimenting with Node.js's query parser and I am able to get it to parse some really complex queries into pretty deeply nested objects and arrays. Some examples:

Query Strings:

```
1) '?$or=foo&$or=bar'
2) '?$or[foo]=bar'
3) '?$or[0][foo]=bar&or[1][bar]=baz'
4)'?$or[0][foo]=bar&or[1][bar][]=baz&or[1][bar][]=bing&or[1][bar][]=bang'
```

Node parses them into:

```
1) { 
    $or: ['foo', 'bar'] 
}

2) { 
    $or: {
        foo: 'bar'
    }
}

3) { 
    $or: [
        { foo: 'bar' }, 
        { bar: 'baz' }
    ]
}

4) { 
    $or: [
        { foo: 'bar' }, 
        { bar: ['baz', 'bing', 'bang'] }
    ]
}
```

This is cool, but I can't find any docs about why this works. I've seen a couple links to [this document](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-1.1), and it has this to say:

> A host identified by an Internet Protocol literal address, version 6 [RFC3513] or later, is distinguished by enclosing the IP literal within square brackets ("[" and "]").  This is the only place where square bracket characters are allowed in the URI syntax.

Sounds like I'm not safe to use this syntax outside of Node at the very least, but why did Node decide it should work this way, and did they document this anywhere?

Comment: _“This is the only place where square bracket characters are allowed in the URI syntax”_ – that only means that you have to properly URL-encode them if you want to use them elsewhere …

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging I discovered in the [express.js 4.x docs](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app-settings) that express's query parser is based on the [qs parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs). I'm running express 3.x, whose documentation doesn't seem to mention qs or any advanced parsing capabilities, yet all of the qs documentation still seems to apply.